# Uploaded Android Bundle doesn't have android:exported property set

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console, rocket.chat

I have an app that is ready for internal testing on the Google Play store. However, when I go to upload the .aab file, I get the error:

> You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle which has an activity, activity alias, service or broadcast receiver with intent filter, but without `android:exported` property set. This file can't be installed on Android 12 or higher. See: developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported

I have tried adding `android:exported="true"` to my AndroidManifest.xml file as suggested in other posts but none of that has worked. I'm not sure what to try next. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Either you have forgotten one place to add it to, or you depend on a library/SDK that imports such XML elements that don't have the "exported" attributes, or you forgot to recompile your app bundle after the changes. If the dependency, then make sure you depend on the latest version of your libraries in case they've already fixed it.

Comment: I have added the `exported` line to every activity in my main/AndoridManifest.xml file. Currently I'm working with the Rocket.Chat.ReactNative repo. It seems that I'm not the only one having an issue with this right now. The official repo isn't even using sdk version 31 yet. They're still on 30.