# Getting Issue when uploading App on Playstore

Tags: react-native, rocket.chat

I have whitelisted Application from Rocketchat React Native

1.App runs on Simulator
2. on Acutal Device

When I am trying to upload it on playstore am getting following error
[error on upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zblwf.jpg)

I have added android:export to all the necessary places ie
AndoridManifest.xml/main AndoridManifest.xml/play

Answer (score 0):

In your AdroidManifest.xml file you should put  `android:exported="true"` to the every `activity` you have.

Comment: I have done that to every activity . Mine issue is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73297965/uploaded-android-bundle-doesnt-have-androidexported-property-set but there has been no update